# RegionIntersection: Point or Line?

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, intersection

This may be a minor point, but I'm wondering why `RegionIntersection`of the two rectangles below gives 3 Lines rather than 2 Lines and 1 Point.

```
rect1 = {AbsoluteThickness[10], Red, r1 = Line[{{0, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 2}}]};
rect2 = {AbsoluteThickness[2], Blue, r2 = Line[{{0, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}; 
Graphics[{rect1, rect2}, Frame -> True]
```

`AbsoluteThickness` was used to show clearly where rect2 (blue) intersects with rect1 (red).

[image: pic1]

---

Now let's display, in purple, the intersection of regions r1, r2.

```
intersection = RegionIntersection[r1, r2]
Graphics[{rect1, rect2, Purple, AbsoluteThickness[10], intersection}, 
         Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

Note that one of the lines, `Line[{{2, 1}}]`, is really a point.
It plots it correctly, as a (very large) point.
But why didn't `RegionIntersection` identify it as  `Point[{2, 1}]`?

> Line[{{{2, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {2, 0}}}]

[image: pic3]

---

If line segments of the rectangles do not overlap, `RegionIntersection` returns Points, as expected. (By the way, I had to add `AbsolutePointSize` here because `AbsoluteThickness` affects Lines but not Points.  The "point" plotted above was actually a line of length 0.)

```
rect3 = {AbsoluteThickness[10], Green, r3 = Line[{{-4, 9}, {4, 9}, {4, 3}, {-4, 3}, {-4, 9}}]};
rect4 = {AbsoluteThickness[2], Gray, r4 = Line[{{2, 10}, {14, 10}, {14, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 10}}]};
intersection = RegionIntersection[r3, r4]
Graphics[{rect3, rect4, Purple, AbsolutePointSize[8], intersection}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

> Point[{{2, 9}, {4, 4}}]

[image: pic4]

Comment: interesting, notice if the intersection is *only* discrete points then `RegionIntersection` does return a `Point` list.

Comment: Yes, I've used `RegionIntersection` in many other cases in which it returns a combination of Points and Lines

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, you may want to send this to support@wolfram.com

Comment: I can't see this as a bug. The result is correct, both mathematically (a  zero-length line is a point) and graphically (it displays as a point). For as long I can remember, _Mathematica_ has always treated `Line[{{{0, 1}}]` and `Line[{{0, 1}}, {{0, 1}}}]` as the same thing.

Comment: Technically, I suppose, a line with no length may be equivalent to a point. However, I would expect Mathematica to return it in its standard form.  In the particular case I am working on, I am trying to count the number of times a line crosses another line.  Of course there is a workaround, but it is a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 3):

Querying the documentation I believe the answer to this question is because of this property of the function called [`RegionEmbeddingDimension`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionEmbeddingDimension.html):

[image]

[image]

**In the first case:**

```
rect1={AbsoluteThickness[10],Red,
r1=Line[{{0,2},{2,2},{2,0},{0,0},{0,2}}]};
rect2={AbsoluteThickness[2],Blue,
r2=Line[{{0,1},{3,1},{3,0},{0,0},{0,1}}]};
intersection1=RegionIntersection[r1,r2]
Graphics[{rect1,rect2,Purple,AbsoluteThickness[10],intersection1},
Frame->True,AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

```
Head[intersection1]
```

> Line

It is the embedding dimension that gives the dimension of space. As the line was the largest dimension, it prevailed

**In the second case:**

```
rect3={AbsoluteThickness[10],Green,
r3=Line[{{-4,9},{4,9},{4,3},{-4,3},{-4,9}}]};
rect4={AbsoluteThickness[2],Gray,
r4=Line[{{2,10},{14,10},{14,4},{2,4},{2,10}}]};
intersection2=RegionIntersection[r3,r4]
Graphics[{rect3,rect4,Purple,AbsolutePointSize[8],intersection2},
Frame->True,AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

```
Head[intersection2]
```

> Point

It is the embedding dimension that gives the dimension of space. As the point was the only dimension, it prevailed